# How to start rare blade Dagas side quest Lost Kingdom?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

I believe I must be missing a step or prerequsite as I am running around Midorl bridge in Mor Ardain upper level at 16:00-18:00 with Kagas equipped as the "first blade" on his driver to no avail. I don't see the trigger. Do I need to max out something on his affinity chart first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had it unlocked at appears you need to have level 5 affinity, and all nodes of cavalier attitude except the last one unlocked. Then show up at midorl bridge around 4pm to 6pm. **Maybe the actual conditions are less demanding.**

**Though maybe you only need cavalier attitude level 2 for the actual gameplay.**

Answer (score 1):

There are two requirements to trigger quest - lvl 5 affinity with Dagas (Trust A or better), and corresponding time (sunset, around 4 pm).

Answer (score 1):

It seems you also need Pyra/Mythra in your party.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the quest to spawn either.  Then I had one other affinity node to finish (gain affinity in combat 0/15 times).

The quest marker showed up for me as soon as I finished that node.  I.e. I completed every other one of the nodes on Dagas' affinity chart besides Cavalier Attitude 5.